# mysql fetch a column value from another table in existing query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have three MySQL tables, successfully have completed a query which does some calculations on payments table to be displayed against orders.

Question:
 Need to fetch a full_name column from sku_mapping table in below mention query join condition is

concat ('f|',fk_orders.sku) = sku_mapping.prefix_sku

fk_orders

```
|order_item_id |order_id    |Invoice_No       |Invoice_No_Amt  |Qty   |Refund_Qty |Refund_Amount | sku
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1131231       |123         |F08OTTN16-1      |100            |1     |            |              |A3001
|1113138       |321         |F08OTTN16-2      |200            |2     |1           |200           |B1001
|1231231       |023         |F08OTTN16-3      |100            |1     |1           |100           |C2001
|1133138       |320         |F08OTTN16-4      |200            |2     |            |              |D8901
|1134231       |103         |F08OTTN16-5      |100            |1     |            |              |E6210
|1113538       |300         |F08OTTN16-6      |200            |2     |            |              |F1001
|1003538       |300         |F08OTTN16-7      |200            |2     |            |              |G9003
```

fk_payments

```
|order_item_id    |order_id    |Invoice_No       |Invoice_No_Amt |Settlement_Value
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|OI:1131231       |123         |F08OTTN16-1      |100            |40
|OI:1113138       |321         |F08OTTN16-2      |200            |150
|OI:1231231       |023         |F08OTTN16-3      |100            |-50
|OI:1133138       |320         |F08OTTN16-4      |200            |200
|OI:1134231       |103         |F08OTTN16-5      |100            |40
|OI:1113538       |300         |F08OTTN16-6      |200            |250
|OI:1131231       |123         |F08OTTN16-1      |100            |40
|OI:1133138       |320         |F08OTTN16-4      |200            |100
|OI:1113138       |321         |F08OTTN16-2      |200            |-200
```

sku_mapping

```
|prefix_sku |full_name 
-------------------
x|A3001     |Apple_Phone
f|B1001     |Belkin
f|C2001     |Cat_Access
f|D8901     |Dlink
f|E6210     |Eltron
f|F1001     |Flag
f|G9003     |gott
f|A3001     |Phone
a|B1001     |Belkin
a|C2001     |Cat_Access
a|D8901     |Dlink
a|E6210     |Eltron
a|F1001     |Flag
a|G9003     |gott
```

Current Result

```
|order_item_id  |order_id   |Invoice_No     |Invoice_No_Amt |Qty    |Refund_Qty |Refund_Amount  |sku    |SettledAmount  |netAmount
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1131231        |123        |F08OTTN16-1    |100            |1      |           |               |A3001  |80             |20
|1113138        |321        |F08OTTN16-2    |200            |2      |1          |200            |B1001  |150            |50
|1231231        |23         |F08OTTN16-3    |100            |1      |1          |100            |C2001  |50             |50 
|1133138        |320        |F08OTTN16-4    |200            |2      |           |               |D8901  |300            |-100
|1134231        |103        |F08OTTN16-5    |100            |1      |           |               |E6210  |40             |60
|1113538        |300        |F08OTTN16-6    |200            |2      |           |               |F1001  |250            |-50
|1003538        |300        |F08OTTN16-7    |200            |2      |           |               |G9003  |0              |200
```

Expected Result (need full_name column from sku_prefix table)

```
|order_item_id  |order_id   |Invoice_No     |Invoice_No_Amt |Qty    |Refund_Qty |Refund_Amount  |sku    |SettledAmount  |netAmount  |full_name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1131231        |123        |F08OTTN16-1    |100            |1      |           |               |A3001  |80             |20         |Apple_Phone
|1113138        |321        |F08OTTN16-2    |200            |2      |1          |200            |B1001  |150            |50         |Belkin
|1231231        |23         |F08OTTN16-3    |100            |1      |1          |100            |C2001  |50             |50         |Cat_Access
|1133138        |320        |F08OTTN16-4    |200            |2      |           |               |D8901  |300            |-100       |Dlink
|1134231        |103        |F08OTTN16-5    |100            |1      |           |               |E6210  |40             |60         |Eltron
|1113538        |300        |F08OTTN16-6    |200            |2      |           |               |F1001  |250            |-50        |Flag
|1003538        |300        |F08OTTN16-7    |200            |2      |           |               |G9003  |0              |200        |gott
```

Current Code

```
select o.*,
       (coalesce(Refund_Amount, 0) + coalesce(sv, 0)) as SettledAmount,
       (Invoice_No_Amt - coalesce(Refund_Amount, 0) - coalesce(sv, 0)) as netAmount
from fk_orders o left join
     (select invoice_no, sum(Settlement_Value) as sv
      from fk_payments
      group by invoice_no
     ) p
     on o.invoice_no = p.invoice_no;
```

Comment: post your current code so people can work from that

Comment: @Matt have added code.Thanks I had missed that

Comment: How are you pulling back sku currently? there is no mention of it in the code, or of it being in the fk_orders table?

Comment: @Matt that is what I what to do.  I guess I need to add the below code but do no how where to place it 
`FROM `fk_orders`,sku_mapping WHERE concat ('f|',fk_orders.`sku`)=sku_mapping.prefix_sku`

Comment: Ok,  you should have mentioned there was an fk_orders.sku in the fk_orders table sample data above

Answer (score 1):

Assuming fk_orders has a sku field.

```
SELECT o.*, sk.full_name, (coalesce(Refund_Amount, 0) + coalesce(sv, 0)) AS SettledAmount, (Invoice_No_Amt - coalesce(Refund_Amount, 0) - coalesce(sv, 0)) AS netAmount
FROM fk_orders o 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT invoice_no, SUM(Settlement_Value) AS sv
           FROM fk_payments
           GROUP BY invoice_no) p ON o.invoice_no = p.invoice_no
INNER JOIN sku_mapping sk ON o.sku = SUBSTRING_INDEX(prefix_sku,'|',-1)
```

Comment: it worked perfectly. Have edited orders table. I had earlier missed to add the sku column

Comment: the above code has issues it had worked with test table. The actual prefix is "f|" I did replace it SUBSTRING_INDEX(prefix_sku,'f|',-1) but the output result invoice sequence is hanged. Also I have about 40000 rows in each table. And each table has many other columns which are not listed above question since just wanted to look tidy. without the innerjoin the code works for 40 K rows too. But if I add the inner join code no result. i have made a small change in the sku_table so you replicate it at your place

Comment: it doesnt matter what is before the `|`, it could be `abc|E3001` and the same code would pick out `E3001`

Comment: need to join only if the prefix is f| (f with pipe) if the changes, Now i have made changes to sample sku_mapping table and the result is not sorted with invoice no. Thanks